# Migrate Kentico Form from staging to Production

Tags: kentico

I have a staging site and production Kentico site, both have same forms. Now my requirement is to make some changes in form fields and design in staging first. Just want to know is there any simple way to move the form changes like form builder changes or changes in layout to prod without any Import/export of whole site?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [enabling Content Staging](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/deploying-websites/content-staging/configuring-content-staging) if you have the Ultimate or EMS license.  If you don't have either of those licenses, then export the form (without the data) from your staging site and import it into your production site.

Comment: I can see the Export option for forms but not import.

Comment: You import objects/sites under the Sites application.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but for some reason it does not showing changes for form fields after import. I have tried with data and without data, but no luck

Comment: Clear your sites cache and restart it.  Did you check the event log, is there any errors pertaining to the import in there?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need import/export the whole site. Go to site, click export:

1. on `Export type` screen: Select your site from dropdown and `Preselect objects changed after specific date` (pick the date so it will take only your form changes)
2. on `Objects selection` go to `website/content management/forms`.
3. Pick your form and uncheck *Export forms data* checkbox

You do not really do import export of the whole site.

Comment: I have tried to import only form but for some reason it does not showing changes for form fields after import. I have tried with data and without data, but no luck .